# How to send json data from advance rest client and then receive in php web API?

Tags: php, ios, json, api

I am writing API's in PHP for the ios developer for that `I am writing the API that receives the array of items` in API firstly I am unable to send the JSON data.
[image]

But I get the response that is not valid you can view the image below.
[image]
So how can I send the JSON array data and get the response? I had developed many apis by sending one key value pair that works fine but not knows how to send the array of items. Here is the code in am try to get the values.

```
require_once('db/db_config.php');
$enable_log = 0;
if ($enable_log) {

$data = ' GET DATA ' . print_r($_GET, 1);
$data = ' GET DATA ' . print_r($_FILES, 1);
$data .= ' POST DATA ' . print_r($_POST, 1);
$time = @date('[d/M/Y:H:i:s]');
error_log($time . $data . PHP_EOL, 3, "login.log");
}
//call to helper function
$app_type = request_check();
$token = isset($_REQUEST['token']) ? $_REQUEST['token'] : '';
$employee_id = isset($_REQUEST['employee_id']) ? $_REQUEST['employee_id'] : '';
$order_item_array = isset($_REQUEST['ordered_items']) ?  $_REQUEST['ordered_items'] : '';

$decode = (array) json_decode($_REQUEST['ordered_items'], true);
echo "<pre>";print_r($decode);exit;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

convert your data into Json and than base 64 and call the url using post you can send a lot of data converting into Json